# Python connect to informix with ibm_db 64bits

Tags: python, windows, informix

I'm trying to connect on Informix db using ibm_db module.

The module install ok.

```
easy_install ibm_db-2.0.5-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
Processing ibm_db-2.0.5-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
removing 'c:\python27-64\lib\site-packages\ibm_db-2.0.5-py2.7-win-amd64.egg' (and everything under it)
creating c:\python27-64\lib\site-packages\ibm_db-2.0.5-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
Extracting ibm_db-2.0.5-py2.7-win-amd64.egg to c:\python27-64\lib\site-packages
ibm-db 2.0.5 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Installed c:\python27-64\lib\site-packages\ibm_db-2.0.5-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
Processing dependencies for ibm-db==2.0.5
Finished processing dependencies for ibm-db==2.0.5
```

but an error raise up when I try import module.

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: N�o foi poss�vel encontrar o m�dulo especificado.
```

Can anyone help me with this issue or knows what are the dll's is needed to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: On windows you need to have the IBM "db2cli.dll" available in the PATH environment variable. The dll should be in the bin directory where the IBM DATA SERVER driver was installed.